# Save scalogram as image

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa

i would like to read wave files from directory,  create  a scalogram image and save inside  another directory,for scalogram creation, i have searched a lot of  tutorial and find this link
[scalogram](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74032/scalograms-in-python),i have applied to my  audio file  and  scalogram is generated pretty  fine, here is image :
[image: scalogram]

only left part is to save it as jpg  format under  some resolution to specific directory, could you tell me please how to do it?i will post code as well

```py
import cv2
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import pywt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ssqueezepy import cwt
from ssqueezepy.visuals import plot, imshow
import librosa

y,sr =librosa.load("genres_original/classical/classical.00000.wav")

# cwtmatr =signal.cwt(y,signal.gau,width)
Wx, scales = cwt(y, 'morlet')
imshow(Wx, yticks=scales, abs=1,
       title="abs(CWT) | Morlet wavelet",
       ylabel="scales", xlabel="samples")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please look at your code and compare it to other examples on StackOverflow, then click [edit] and correct it - you don't want folks having to scroll past Japan and into Hawaii to read it

Comment: `plt.savefig()` looks a likely candidate.

Comment: Stackoverflow requires that code should be  shifted  by 4 space in order to accept code, so i have done  what was required from this site. dont judge  code by spaces

Comment: what if i dont want to display image and save in background mode?

Comment: If that was what you wanted you would surely click [edit] and put it in your question... while moving your code back West. Questions need to be *"minimal, complete and reproducible"* on StackOverflow so that answerers, who are unpaid volunteers, don't need to keep asking for clarification, or discovering new constraints buried in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for  recomendation, what about question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `plt.savefig('filename.jpg')` to the end will save a JPEG image of the entire plot - including axes markers, titles etc.

In order to avoid showing the plot on screen, you need to remove the call to plt.show() and explicitly create the figure and axes.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
imshow(fig=fig, ax=ax, show=0, ....)
```

If what you want is to save the 2d array that is the *data* of the scaleogram (for further processing), then you should use something like `numpy.savez('filename.npy', wx=Wx, scales=scales)`.

Comment: does it saves as  image?

Comment: A JPEG is an image. So yes, the first approach does save as an image.

Comment: problem is that  is  shows image every time and i should  canceal, so question is how to save images for all  audio files without  show images on screen?

Comment: That was not mentioned in your question... But sure, see updated answer.

Comment: so how can i  create  spectrogram and save it  without showing on screen? please pay attention that if i directly save  spectrogram without scales  usage, it shows just  white screen

Comment: The answer has all the points needed for that. What is unclear?

Comment: i did not get  point to be honest

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import pywt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ssqueezepy import cwt
from ssqueezepy.visuals import plot, imshow
import librosa

y,sr =librosa.load("genres_original/classical/classical.00000.wav")

# cwtmatr =signal.cwt(y,signal.gau,width)
Wx, scales = cwt(y, 'morlet')
imshow(Wx, yticks=scales, abs=1,
       title="abs(CWT) | Morlet wavelet",
       ylabel="scales", xlabel="samples", show=0)
plt.savefig('filename.jpg')
```

To save the images, you just need to modify the code by changing `show=0`. Then use `plt.savefig('filename.jpg')` after it.